# Trying to automatically add indent in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, indentation

I'm using the data bars in Excel, and I want the negative numbers to come on the left side of the midpoint, and the postive numbers on the right side of it.
I'm currently using

```
.Offset(Rowcount, 13).Value = Me.TextBox13.Value
```

Is there any way how I can achive this with, for example, indents?

Example, something like this:

```
   -15|
      |20
      |12
   -17|
```

Comment: @KenWhite Databars **are** conditional formatting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

With the data bars already in place, format the cells to center the contents. Then apply a custom number format to the cells, using

0;-0

The trick is to apply a few leading spaces in front of the positive number format, and a few trailing spaces after the negative number format. That will offset the numbers from the center line. You may need to play around with the number of space characters required for the optimum result.

[image]

Comment: Not so neat but I'd still say it's clever :)